# OceanWP Settings Panel won't open / doesn't show

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am trying to work with OceanWP, but it just seems that the settings panel won't open. I have Elementor and the essential Addons for Elementor, I activated the OceanWP Theme, is there a plugin I still need to Install besides the Ocean Extra? I can't find anything to solve this on the internet.

Thanks in advance!

I tried reinstalling the plugins or deactivating some of them and clearing my browser cache, it just doesn't change anything